# Moving text in a div vertically (except text-align)

Tags: html, css, position, text-align

I need to move text in div vertically. It work with text-align but i need specific position(for example 2 px from the top). I tried it with position absolute,relative, static; margin ; padding . It is moving with div no with text. I created simple example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm1o1j6e/) . Is it possible?

Html code:

```
<div class="usp">
    <ul id="menu1">
        <li>
            <a class="nav4" data-tab="#football" id="link-football" href="#football">Channel&nbsp;1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="nav5" data-tab="#football_ch2" id="link-football_ch2" href="#football_ch2">Channel&nbsp;2</a>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <a class="nav6" data-tab="#football_ch3" id="link-football_ch3" href="#football_ch3">Channel&nbsp;3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#menu1  {
    width: 100px;
    height:70px;
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    z-index:3;

 }  
#menu1 a{   
    color:#3D3D3D;   
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", sans-serif   ; 
    letter-spacing: -0.035em;
    display: block;
    line-height: 28px;  /*29*/
    text-align:left;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size:0.922em; /*895*/
    font-weight:bold;
    opacity:0.90;   /*88 or 91*/
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;    /*6*/
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 30px 0px rgba(51, 50, 50, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow:    1px 0px 30px 0px rgba(51, 50, 50, 1);
    box-shadow:         1px 0px 30px 0px rgba(51, 50, 50, 1);
 }  
 #menu1 a:visited {  


 } 

 #menu1 a:hover {  
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#333333;
 }  
.usp{
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:190px;

    }
```

Comment: Move? As in movement? Text seems pretty vertically aligned to me... Your `line-height` does that.

Comment: How come you say that `text-align` works if you are talking about *vertical* alignment??  Or are you?

Comment: in demo is text centered (text align center) but i need specific position for example 2 px from the top ... I created simple demo my problem , real project is other

Comment: `position: relative;` to menu's container, `position: absolute; top: 2px;` to the menu.

Comment: Your question is not clear!!! Do you want to position top 2px the text "Channel #" inside the menu??

Comment: yes i want to position text of links

Comment: @Fakt7 Check my answer and let me know if this is what you are looking for!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If you are looking for this output > http://jsfiddle.net/9af6bLwp/

Just remove "<strike>`line-height: 28px;`</strike>"

And add padding as per requirement `padding: 0 0 10px;`

Here is the updated code:

```
#menu1 a {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -0.035em;
    display: block;
    /* line-height: 28px; */
    text-align: center; /*CHANGED*/
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 0.922em;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0.90;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0px 30px 0px rgba(51, 50, 50, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0px 30px 0px rgba(51, 50, 50, 1);
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 30px 0px rgba(51, 50, 50, 1);
    padding: 0 0 10px; /*CHANGE THE TOP PADDING AS PER YOUR NEED*/
}
```

Also, just to correct few more things, to center align the text you were using below code:

```
text-align:left; /*Aligned text to left*/
padding: 0px 20px; /*Added 20px Padding to Left and Right to push the text to look like center */
```

I simply changed the left and right padding to be "`0`", and made the text to be align center using `text-align: center;`

Hope this will helps!!!

Comment: i tried it in my project and it work. Thanks for help. And yes it is what i've been looking for